# How to interpolate and check correlation of RDDs with differing cardinality in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, statistics, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to check how correlated two RDDs are with time, but they don't have the same cardinality (i.e., they have different number of data points because the timestamps the data are collected are different). I see from the Statistics API that the same number of partitions and cardinality is necessary. Below is some example code. I tried to look for some interpolation library in Spark to achieve the same number of partitions and cardinality, but I found none. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone else has experience or advice on this one. Thanks.

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

sc = ... # SparkContext

seriesX = ... # a series
seriesY = ... # must have the same number of partitions and cardinality as seriesX

# Compute the correlation using Pearson's method. Enter "spearman" for Spearman's method. If a 
# method is not specified, Pearson's method will be used by default. 
print Statistics.corr(seriesX, seriesY, method="pearson")

data = ... # an RDD of Vectors
# calculate the correlation matrix using Pearson's method. Use "spearman" for Spearman's method.
# If a method is not specified, Pearson's method will be used by default. 
print Statistics.corr(data, method="pearson")
```

**UPDATE:** I found a Python package call [traces](http://traces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that does what I want. How can I incorporate it into the Spark computations, i.e. applying it in parallel to the partitions?